# jQuery how to do the following

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I've the following question, let say we have a div like this:

[image]

These are dynamically formatted divs, with the classes 'row', 'element' and 'isotope-item' are always present. Everything in between can vary per div.

What I want is to the following:
[image]

As you see the commmas are no longer there and seperate classes between the commas are now one class.

Anyone any idea?

I already have the following to remove the commas:

```
$('div.element').each(function () {
        var _sCurrClasses = jQuery(this).attr('class');
        jQuery(this).attr('class', _sCurrClasses.replace(/,/g, ' '));
    });
```

Comment: Everything is possible, if you put some effort in order to do that : ))

Comment: your concept is wrong here, you should remove comma and spaces from your server side language jquery is not ideal choice for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise doing this backend,but in JavaScript you could:
This will not account for the space in the words though.
You would need to pass then trough separately one by one and replace.
or store them in a data-attribute and format when you need them.

```
<string>
var classesFormat = classes.replace(/,/g, '');
var classesList = classesFormat.split(" ");

for(String c : classesList)
{
    $("#id").addClass(c);
}
</string>
```

So you could create a data-attribute for each one instead.
Go through each one, format and the add to class.

```
<div data-id="Microsoft Office," class="test test test">
```

With the script

```
$(this).attr("data-id") // will return the string "Microsoft Office,"
```

or .data() (if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3)

```
$(this).data("id") // will return the Microsoft Office,
```

And then do your replace after that and addClass.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think classes work like you think they do

the first PICTURE you posted would result in that div having the follwing classes

- row
- element
- Microsoft
- Office,
- My
- SQL,
- Page
- Rank
- isotope-item

Note the , is PART of the class

You want, according to the second PICTURE

- row
- element
- MicrosoftOffice
- MySQL
- Page
- Rank
- isotope-item

Removing `,` is just as you posted ... the problem is, how do you determine which spaces to remove, and which to keep?

**(I posted this as an ANSWER, but I KNOW IT IS NOT AN ANSWER)**